# Setting resolution in JIRA with Greenhopper

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I added a new resolution in our JIRA/Greenhopper setup, but I cannot use it because the 'Resolve' button in missing from the issue screen.

Can I bring the the button somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the underlying JIRA workflow to use a transition screen that shows the Resolution field

Comment: As in, create a new transition with the screen which shows the resolution field?