# Multiple Steps for Resolved in JIRA/Greenhopper

Tags: jira, jira-agile

In JIRA a resolved issue can have different resolutions: e.g. Won't Fix, Cannot Reproduce, Fixed etc. I had been using JIRA without Greenhopper and using these resolutions was part of the workflow.

Now I'm using JIRA+Greenhopper with Kanban boards and I'm trying to extend the workflow to have few *steps* associated with the Resolved step:

- *In QA* which is Status:Resolved,Resolution:Done;
- *Won't Fix* which is Status:Resolved,Resolution:Done;
- *Backlog* which is Status:Resolved,Resolution:Backlog;
- etc;

When trying to edit the workflow I learned that it is not possible to have two steps that correspond to one status (*Resolved*). Is this the case?

At the moment it actually is not possible to set the issue to any resolution different than *Done* as

- the 'Resolve' button is not available on the issue screens (I already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18307168/setting-resolution-in-jira-with-greenhopper) about the missing button).
- I have tried to set up a new transition which would move the issue into Status:Resolved, Resolution:Won't Fix but I'm hitting the problem that for active workflows if there are no outgoing transitions already defined you cannot create new ones.

**Questions**: 
Is it possible possible to map two workflow steps to one status? Am I missing something and the *Won't Fix*, *Cannot reproduce* resolutions don't fit into the Greenhopper way of thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend creating a JIRA workflow from scratch and provide detailed steps in Practical JIRA Administration (O'Reilly). I also recommend having a 1:1 mapping of JIRA step name to status name, and JIRA doesn't do 2:1 mapping. I think you probably want to create new statuses for your workflow, e.g. In QA.

The system resolution field is designed as a kind of sub-status for one, maybe two, statuses. People usually use it just with Closed.